# One big figure over three smallones in a beamer frame?

Tags: beamer, split

How can I put 1 big figure with 3 small evenly sized figures below it in a beamer frame?  I've used subfigure for splitting but that gives even sized thangs which isn't what I'm going for ... :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You could achieve this with simple LaTeX methods.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Figures}
\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{\textheight}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=3cm]{example-image}\\
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}
\end{center}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and the warm welcome...so helpful (I'd upvote the answer but I don't have enough reputation yet :0 )